# Why are my channels deadlocking?

Tags: go

I am trying to program a simple Go script that calculates the sum of the natural numbers up to 8:

```
package main
import "fmt" 

func sum(nums []int, c chan int) {
    var sum int = 0
    for _, v := range nums {
        sum += v    
    }
    c <- sum
}

func main() {
    allNums := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
    c1 := make(chan int)
    c2 := make(chan int)
    sum(allNums[:len(allNums)/2], c1)
    sum(allNums[len(allNums)/2:], c2)
    a := <- c1
    b := <- c2
    fmt.Printf("%d + %d is %d :D", a, b, a + b)
}
```

However, running this program produces the following output.

```
throw: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.sum(0x44213af00, 0x800000004, 0x420fbaa0, 0x2f29f, 0x7aaa8, ...)
    main.go:9 +0x6e
main.main()
    main.go:16 +0xe6

goroutine 2 [syscall]:
created by runtime.main
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:221

exit status 2
```

Why is my code deadlocking? I am confused because I am using 2 separate channels to calculate the sub-sums. How are the two channels dependent at all?

Comment: Think about to whom you're sending stuff when you send something over a channel. Keep in mind that your channels are unbuffered, so sending on a channel will block until someone reads from that channel.

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/xyW_KfsFv7 or http://play.golang.org/p/Ni-vmvKg2K

Comment: Oh thanks! So without the `go` statements, I'm sending data from a thread to itself. The thread thus waits for itself to receive before returning from the call to send data into the channel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to add `go` like

```
go sum(allNums[:len(allNums)/2], c1)

go sum(allNums[len(allNums)/2:], c2)
```

or

```
c1 := make(chan int,1)
c2 := make(chan int,1)
```

add channel cache.

Answer (score 6):

Your channels are unbuffered, so the `c <- sum` line in `sum()` will block until some other routine reads from the other end.

One option would be to add buffers to the channels, so you can write a value to the channel without it blocking:

```
c1 := make(chan int, 1)
c2 := make(chan int, 1)
```

Alternatively, if you run the `sum()` function as a separate goroutine, then it can block while your `main()` function continues to the point where it reads from the channels.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used Go in a while, so this may not be the case, but from what I remember you need `go` to get another goroutine started, so:

```
go sum(allNums[:len(allNums)/2], c1)
go sum(allNums[len(allNums)/2:], c2)
```

If `sum` isn't running on another goroutine, it tries to execute:

```
c <- sum
```

But nothing's reading `c`; the code reading `c` has not been reached yet because it's waiting for `sum` to finish, and `sum` won't finish because it needs to give it to that code first!